# Django Admin - Prevent Inline Showing When Adding a New Object

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two one-to-one related models in Django. Simplified version as follows:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Profile(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have used signals to automatically create a profile automatically when a new user is created.

I have also created a ProfileInline and included it in my UserAdmin as follows:

```
class ProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
    inlines = [ProfileInline,]
```

The problem I am facing is that when a new User is being created in the admin module, and the person creating the new user also populates the field for the inline on the same page, an error is generated while saving because both the signals module and the admin are trying to create a new Profile.

Is there any way to prevent the ProfileInline from showing in the UserAdmin when adding a new User?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add `extra=0` in your `ProfileInline` to prevent create new profile instance when you create new User at admin side...

```
    class ProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Profile
        can_delete = False
        extra = 0
    class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('name',)
        inlines = [ProfileInline,]
```

**OR** You can use ModelAdmin `get_inline_instances` function. Following code removes **inlines** from `add_view`:

```
    class ProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Profile
        can_delete = False
    
    class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('name',)
        inlines = [ProfileInline,]
    
        def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
            return obj and super(UserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj) or []
```

Comment: Thank you. This works to stop the form from appearing, but there is still an "Add another Profile" which appears. Is there any way to suppress this as well?

Comment: Hello @ankGT please check my updated answer..Here `Profile form` suppress in admin side..